# Heat equation in 2D as separable system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In class, we solved the simple 1D heat equation

$$\alpha^2U_{xx}=U_t$$

by assuming $U(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ and obtaining a constant $\lambda$ which transforms the equation into a system of two ODEs.

Given instead a 2D system

$$\alpha^2\nabla^2U=U_t$$

Say I want to separate this into a system of ODEs. So I assume there is a solution of form $U(x,y,t)=X(x)Y(y)T(t)$. Then

$$\begin{split}
\alpha^2\nabla^2U & =U_t \\
\alpha^2(X''YT+XY''T) & =XYT'
\end{split}$$

and

$$\alpha^2\frac{T}{T'}=\frac{XY}{X''Y+XY''}=\lambda_1$$

then, focusing on the RHS

$$XY=\lambda_1(X''Y+XY'')\Rightarrow1=\lambda_1\left(\frac{X''}X+\frac{Y''}Y\right)$$

again, on the RHS:

$$1-\lambda_1\frac{Y''}Y=\lambda_1\frac{X''}X=\lambda_2$$

Therefore, our ODEs are

$$1-\lambda_1Y''/Y=\lambda_2$$
$$\lambda_1X''/X=\lambda_2$$
$$\alpha^2T/T'=\lambda_1$$

**Is this a good extension of the methods I learned in class?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks all fine to me, just be careful when it comes to the *signs* of your constants $\lambda_i$ and how they are all related to each other! You'll also need to apply boundary conditions after you've found your general solutions.

Comment: Maybe I should make my constants negative so that it works out better, but I'm happy I got a working solution on the first try.